# How does Popup send message to Content and get response continuously and vise-versa?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, windows-runtime, content-script

What I'd like to do is to:

```
Popup Send Data Request to Content -> Content Receive Request, Send Data (listData) -> Popup Receive Data.
```

Then, if content change its elements,

```
Content Send Message -> Popup Receive Message, Send Request Data -> Content Receive Request, Send Data (listData) -> Popup Receive Data
```

I have this code in `Content.tsx`

```
new MutationObserver(() => {
    var dataImage: any = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
    var dataName: any = document.getElementsByClassName('name');
    var dataTitle: any = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

    var listData: Array<any> = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < dataImage.length; x++) {
      const image = dataImage[x]?.firstElementChild?.src;
      const name = dataName[x]?.innerText;
      const title = dataTitle[x]?.firstElementChild?.innerText;
      const web = dataName[x]?.firstElementChild?.href;

      listData.push({
        image: image,
        name: name,
        title: title,
        web: web,
      });
    }

    
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendMessage) {
      if (request.greeting === 'hello') {sendMessage(listData)};
    });
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(listData)
}).observe(document, { subtree: true, childList: true });
```

And this in `Popup.tsx`

```
getLeadList(query: Object): Promise<LeadResult[]> {
    return new Promise<LeadResult[]>(
      (resolve: (value: LeadResult[]) => void) => {
        chrome.tabs.query(
          { active: true, currentWindow: true },
          function (tabs: any) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
              tabs[0].id,
              { greeting: 'hello' },
              function (response) {
                if (response) {
                  resolve(response);
                }
              }
            );
          }
        );
            chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request: LeadResult[]) => {
          if (request) {
            resolve(request);
          }
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

What is happening right now is that Popup only send message once. So if you close the Popup and the url in content wasn't reload, Popup wont get the new content from `Content.tsx` and it only has the initial data from content. Also as you can see, I used direct `sendMessage` since if Content have changes, it passes the `listdata` in realtime. Although I'm not yet familiar with the proper use of chrome.runtime, so I'm open with correction in my misused code.

What I'd like to do is to Popup get the updated `listdata` when scrolled by `MutationObserver`. Then, if the Popup was closed, it will retrieve the latest scrolled data from `MutationObserver`. Also, make the Popup reload the Content Page when it clicked to open. (Like window.reload or soemthing)

Hope you could help me figure this thing.
Thank you very much.

Comment: It can be simplified to chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, callback), see [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: So, i dont need to use the tab? and only just chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, callback)?

Comment: Question. Does chrome.tabs from Popup to Content is one way? Is there a way to receive the updated data from Content to Popup through using chrome.tabs?

Comment: If your content script is the initiator, it uses chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, callback) and the popup answers in its onMessage. If the popup is the initiator, it uses chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg, callback) and the content script answers in its onMessage.

Comment: Supposedly, popup should be my initiator. but since, i think its only one way, I couldn't pass back the `listData` if it has updated values from content to popup. Which is why, I had `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg, callback)`  in the content, which passes the updated `listData` in realtime.

Comment: But when popup is closed, it wont retrieve the latest value of `listData` and only has the inital value when tabs triggered at first time

Comment: What I mean is. For example, when you click popup, it will get 4 datas. Then if you scroll in the page, content send the updated `listData` to popup, which for example will now be 10 datas. Then, if you close the popup, and open again, the 4 datas are only retrieved and not the 10 datas. Is there a way so the popup to content will get the updated `listdata`? @wOxxOm

Comment: The popup runs each time when it's shown so at the start of its script you should send a message to the content script and ask for **all** data again.

Comment: Basically,  i'll be having `chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, msg, callback)` to request to content first. then, what `chrome.runtime` should i use to send a message again to content to ask again?

Comment: is it the long live connection? @wOxxOm

Comment: When the popup opens you can use chrome.tabs.sendMessage to get all data. Additionally, the content script can use chrome.runtime.sendMessage when it detects new data.

Comment: Then, my code above is right then? I used sendMessage from content to pass the `listData` back to popup. So, the current happening with my code is that popup will only get the updated `listData` when the extension is open and the page was scrolled. But if you close the popup, it wont retrieve the latest sendMessage and it will only show na initial or first time data that chrome.tabs got. Unless, I scrolled in the page, it will get the latest `listData` from content to popup. Is there any way that the data before close will be retrieved when the popup open again? @wOxxOm

Comment: What i'd like to do is that, if you have 10 datas before closing the popup. if you close and open it again, popup will stilll have the 10 datas. Currently in my code, if popup first request was only 4 datas, then the data updated to 10 datas when scrolled. if you close and open it again, the 4 datas will popup get. even though the `listData` in content is updated @wOxxOm

Comment: hope you could help me figure this out.. ive been stuck here for almost 1 week, just to figure it out.. i already search in youtube and google, but i cant seem to find related works with my issue that i can relate. T_T @wOxxOm